# Select a random number representing a row

Tags: sql, oracle, random, plsql

How can i make this thing in PL/SQL?

I want to generate a random number, which will represent a position (row) from a list of results, which will be ordered by a field.

To give a more detailed thing, suppose we have

ID : 1,5,7,9,11,20,35

How can I generate a random number, that will be from these (1,5,7,9,11,20,35) ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select id
from   ( select id, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value()) as rn
         from   your_table
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

In the subquery, you assign a random number to each row, and then you order the rows by these random numbers. In the outer query you select the row with the lowest assigned random number. In reality, random numbers are assigned to each row, but there is no ordering of all rows; the Oracle optimizer "understands" the query just picks up the row with the minimum random number, and only does the work needed to achieve that result.

Comment: How should the query be modified, if the random number we want to generate is actually the position (ROW) in the ascending order.  For the initial example, ID 1 has position 1, ID 5 has position 2, ID 7 has position 3 and so on..

Comment: @zowie - in the subquery, in addition to `id` and `row_number()... as rn`, select also `row_number() over (order by id) as rid`, and in the outer query `select id, rid` - this will tell you if the first, or third, or sixth row was selected, in addition to giving you the id.

Comment: I tried to make what you said. Considering i want to print that value, using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, it's impossible to select both id,rid.. cause i have to use SELECT ID INTO "my_variable".. (if you understand what i say).. I understand your idea with subquery and outer query but I can't make that row_number over (order by id).

Comment: @zowie - again I don't understand. If you need to select just that value, then in the outer select put only `rid`, don't put `id`. If you need **both** values (the `id` as well as the row number) then you need two variables in your PL/SQL code to begin with. Where's the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT  id  from t  
 order by DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE  
 OFFSET 0  ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but something like this:

```
DECLARE
    new_array dbms_sql.varchar2_table;
BEGIN
    new_array(1) := 1;
    new_array(2) := 5;
    new_array(3) := 7;
    new_array(4) := 9;
    new_array(5) := 11;
    new_array(6) := 20;
    new_array(7) := 35;
    ar_count := new_array.count;
    rand_val := dbms_random.value(1,ar_count);
    dbms_output.put_line('Random from specific range '|| new_array(rand_val));
```

Comment: We are probably asked to see this as a procedure. If so, where is the `end;` at the end?

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the range of random numbers using the Modulus operation. Then just by ordering the values as you like and using `ROWNUM` you can get the position of the selected row and its ID.
Here is a code which uses a randomly generated data set using the IDs you provided.

```sql
WITH ds
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id,
                'tZdDNhGWzpAgYUA' AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 5 AS id,
                'yRuHolwoqySVhMTa' AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 7 AS id,
                'EZxaVsoQyIM' AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 9 AS id,
                'WLS' AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 11 AS id,
                'GJEatZb' AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 20 AS id,
                'SoQUTNLdbeXSnMxRnMw' AS val
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 35 AS id,
                'GHTzCzkqQGZGGDtjcCzW' AS val
         FROM   DUAL),
     rand_id
     AS (SELECT MOD (ABS (DBMS_RANDOM.random ()), c)
                + 1
                   AS r_id
         FROM   (SELECT COUNT (*) AS c FROM ds))
SELECT b.rn AS position,
       b.id
FROM   rand_id a,
       (SELECT ROWNUM AS rn,
               id,
               val
        FROM   ds
        ORDER BY id) b
WHERE  a.r_id = b.rn;
```